# Map or/and filter to select elements in React

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, filter

I have code that's working almost fine. Almost, because I need to get all objects where presents **Joe**, but I get either two or one, depending on which of qoute.fields.user / qoute.fields.company is the first.
So, these is my data that looks something like this:

```
{
 id:1;
 user: joe;
 company: foo
},
{
 id:2;
 user: foo;
 company: joe
},
{
 id:3;
 user: joe;
 company: foo2
}
```

If I run this part

```
const user = "joe";

const qoutes = this.state.qoutes.map((qoute, i) => 
user === qoute.fields.user && qoute.fields.company ? 
<ListItem id={i} key={i} qoute={qoute} />
: null)
```

I got id:1 and id:3.
If I change this part and put company first like this:

```
 user === qoute.fields.company && qoute.fields.user ?
```

I got id:2

What should I do to get all three id. (id:1, id:2, id:3) All these objects have Joe. 
I know it's probably easy solution but I got stuck with it) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in pseudo code is:

```
if user = 'joe' and company is not null (return 1,3)

if company = 'joe' and user is not null (return 2)
```

Test user and company and combine them with OR `||` instead of AND `&&`:

```
const qoutes = this.state.qoutes.map((qoute, i) => 
user === qoute.fields.user || user === qoute.fields.company ? 
<ListItem id={i} key={i} qoute={qoute} />
: null)
```

Comment: I knew it's easy) Thanks!